# Is "Length of Longest Increasing Subsequence" in L?

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, space-complexity, subsequences, longest-increasing-subsequence

I can't find space complexity of this problem with search engines.

I think I have NL algorithm for it (just a basic "one by one non-deterministically accept values if possible"), but I wonder what other research was done on it.

Any references and/or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

closest I could find so far:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.08498 provides an SC algoritgm (polylog space, poly time) for approximation of LIS

savitch seems to give smallest space so far